# Uniform convergence of sequence of functions on compact set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact topologial space, $U$ an open subset of $\mathbb R$ and $f:X\to\mathbb R$ a continuous function such that $f(X)\subseteq U$. Prove that if a sequence of functions $f_n:X\to\mathbb R$ uniformly converges to $f$, then there exists $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $n>n_0\,\Rightarrow\,f_n(X)\subseteq U$.

(NB: $f$ is continuous but the $f_n$ themselves are not necessarily continuous.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume this is not true, then for all $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, you can find $n > n_0$, $f_n(X) \not\in U$.

This allows you to build a sequence $x_n$ such that $f_{\phi(n)}(x_n) \not\in U$ where $\phi$ is an extraction.

$X$ being compact and $f$ continuous, $f(X)$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ so it's also sequentially compact and you can extract from $f(x_n)$ a sequence $f(x_{\psi(n)})$ that converges to $y_0 \in f(X)$. So there exists $x_0$ in $X$ such that $f(x_{\psi(n)}) \to f(x_0) = y_o$.

On the other hand, $f$ being continuous, $f(x_{\psi(n)}) \to f(x_0)$. And $U$ being open, there exists a neighbourhood of $x_0$ in $U$ : $\exists \epsilon > 0, B(f(x_0),\epsilon) \in U$

Using all these facts, we can see that actually the initial sequence has to be in $U$ for n large enough :

- since $f_n \to f$, $\exists n_0,\forall n \geq n_0, ||f_n-f||_{\infty} < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$
- since $f(x_{\psi(n)}) \to f(x_0)$, $\exists n_1, \forall n \geq n_1, | f(x_{\psi(n)}) - f(x_0) | < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$

Then, for $n \geq max(n_0,n_1)$, we have that

$|f_{\psi(\phi(n))}(x_{\psi(n)}) - f(x_0)| = |f_{\psi(\phi(n))}(x_{\psi(n)}) - f(x_{\psi(n)}) + f(x_{\psi(n)}) - f(x_0)| \\
\leq |f_{\psi(\phi(n))}(x_{\psi(n)}) - f(x_{\psi(n)})| + |f(x_{\psi(n)}) - f(x_0)| \\
\leq ||f_{\psi(\phi(n))} - f||_{\infty} + |f(x_{\psi(n)}) - f(x_0)| \\
\leq \frac{\epsilon}{4} + \frac{\epsilon}{4} = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

which means that $f_{\psi(\phi(n))}(x_{\psi(n)}) \in B(f(x_0),\epsilon) \subset X$ but that contradicts the definition of $x_n$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You said: “$X$ being compact, you can extract from $x_n$ a sequence $x_{\psi(n)}$ that converges to $x_0$ in $X$.” Doesn’t this apply to sequentially compact spaces rather than compact spaces?

Comment: You're right, I automatically assumed that X was a metric space but it's not true...Actually I didn't need that $x_{\psi(n)} \to x_0$, I just use the convergence of $f(x_{\psi(n)}) \to f(x_0)$. So I corrected the proof to use the fact that in a metric space (as in $\mathbb{R}$), the two notions are the same.